# Generating a graph with certain degree distribution?

Tags: python, algorithm, r, graph, networkx

I am trying to generate a random graph that has small-world properties (exhibits a power law distribution). I just started using the networkx package and discovered that it offers a variety of random graph generation. Can someone tell me if it possible to generate a graph where a given node's degree follows a gamma distribution (either in R or using python's networkx package)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the configuration model something like this should work in NetworkX:

```
import random 
import networkx as nx
z=[int(random.gammavariate(alpha=9.0,beta=2.0)) for i in range(100)]
G=nx.configuration_model(z)
```

You might need to adjust the mean of the sequence z depending on parameters in the gamma distribution.  Also z doesn't need to be graphical (you'll get a multigraph), but it does need an even sum so you might have to try a few random sequences (or add 1)...

The NetworkX documentation notes for configuration_model give another example, a reference and how to remove parallel edges and self loops:

```
Notes
-----
As described by Newman [1]_.

A non-graphical degree sequence (not realizable by some simple
graph) is allowed since this function returns graphs with self
loops and parallel edges.  An exception is raised if the degree
sequence does not have an even sum.

This configuration model construction process can lead to
duplicate edges and loops.  You can remove the self-loops and
parallel edges (see below) which will likely result in a graph
that doesn't have the exact degree sequence specified.  This
"finite-size effect" decreases as the size of the graph increases.

References
----------
.. [1] M.E.J. Newman, "The structure and function
       of complex networks", SIAM REVIEW 45-2, pp 167-256, 2003.

Examples
--------
>>> from networkx.utils import powerlaw_sequence
>>> z=nx.create_degree_sequence(100,powerlaw_sequence)
>>> G=nx.configuration_model(z)

To remove parallel edges:

>>> G=nx.Graph(G)

To remove self loops:

>>> G.remove_edges_from(G.selfloop_edges())
```

Here is an example similar to the one at http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/degree_histogram.html that makes a drawing including a graph layout of the largest connected component:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def seq(n):
    return [random.gammavariate(alpha=2.0,beta=1.0) for i in range(100)]    
z=nx.create_degree_sequence(100,seq)
nx.is_valid_degree_sequence(z)
G=nx.configuration_model(z)  # configuration model

degree_sequence=sorted(nx.degree(G).values(),reverse=True) # degree sequence
print "Degree sequence", degree_sequence
dmax=max(degree_sequence)

plt.hist(degree_sequence,bins=dmax)
plt.title("Degree histogram")
plt.ylabel("count")
plt.xlabel("degree")

# draw graph in inset 
plt.axes([0.45,0.45,0.45,0.45])
Gcc=nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)[0]
pos=nx.spring_layout(Gcc)
plt.axis('off')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(Gcc,pos,node_size=20)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gcc,pos,alpha=0.4)

plt.savefig("degree_histogram.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Aric: Thank you. I understand why it needs an even sum but can you please explain why a multigraph will do? From my understanding, multigraph allows self-loops and multiple edges from a node so I am a little confused.

Comment: @Aric: I can understand that in a multigraph, multiple edges can be merged to form a single edge and loops are erased but will this lead to a simple graph? I am asking this because I tried setting `z = [3,2,2,1]` to generate a simple graph with these degrees but instead I got a graph with `1 2 2 1` degrees.

Comment: You are correct that multigraphs may have self-loops and parallel edges.

Comment: I'm not sure why the small graph you build didn't have the correct degree sequence (old NetworkX version?).    nx.configuration_model([3,2,2,1]).degree().values() gives
[3, 2, 2, 1]

Comment: @Aric: I guess you are right. I updated my networkx version. Thank you very much for the pointers and your time. As a last step, I just came across this `http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/drawing/degree_histogram.html` and looks like you are its author(?) Could you tell me how to plot this graph similar to the one shown in the source file. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a modified version of that example that makes a degree histogram (instead of a degree rank plot).  It also calls create_degree_sequence() which attempts to make a graphical sequence of integers though all you need for the configuration model is an even sum.

Comment: When I run the the first four lines of code in from this answer (import random 
import networkx as nx
z=[int(random.gammavariate(alpha=9.0,beta=2.0)) for i in range(100)]
G=nx.configuration_model(z)) I get this error: float() argument must be a string or a number . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I did this a while ago in base Python... IIRC, I used the following method. From memory, so this may not be entirely accurate, but hopefully it's worth something:

1. Chose the number of nodes, N, in your graph, and the density (existing edges over possible edges), D. This implies the number of edges, E.
2. For each node, assign its degree by first choosing a random positive number x and finding P(x), where P is your pdf. The node's degree is (P(x)*E/2) -1.
3. Chose a node at random, and connect it to another random node. If either node has realized its assigned degree, eliminate it from further selection. Repeat E times.

N.B. that this doesn't create a connected graph in general.

Comment: Thank you for this. This approach is similar (but not the same) to random graph creation but I was worried because for a given degree sequence, there is no guarantee that we can construct a simple graph. But in any case, thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems that something at least similar to this approach is implemented in networkx: [random_degree_sequence_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late, but you can do the same thing, albeit a little more straightforward, with mathematica.

RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}], 4]

This will generate 4 random graphs, with each node having a prescribed degree.

Answer (score 1):

Including the above mentioned, `networkx` provides 4 algorithms that receives the degree_distribution as an input:

- [configuration_model](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.configuration_model): explain by @eric
- [expected_degree_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.expected_degree_graph.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.expected_degree_graph): use a probabilistic approach based on the expected degree of each node. It won't give you the exact degrees but an approximation.
- [havel_hakimi_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.havel_hakimi_graph.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.havel_hakimi_graph): this one tries to connect the nodes with highest degree first
- [random_degree_sequence_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.random_degree_sequence_graph): as far as I can see, this is similar to what @JonC suggested; it has a `trials` parameter as there is no guarantee of finding a suitable configuration.

The full list (including some versions of the algorithms for directed graphs) is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generators.html#degree-sequence).

I also found a couple of papers:

- [Efficient and exact sampling of simple graphs with given arbitrary degree sequence](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0010012)
- [A Sequential Importance Sampling Algorithm for Generating Random Graphs with Prescribed Degrees](http://www.internetmathematicsjournal.com/article/1494)

Answer (score 0):

For a more general and detailed implementation, consider investigating the algorithm described in [*Generating simple random graphs with prescribed degree distribution*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.06985) by Britton et al.

It's likely more detailed than what you need and somewhat impractical, but it provides a potential alternative to the other answers.