# Python: Create a graph with defined number of edges per node

Tags: python, networkx

How I can create a graph with

-predefined number of connections for each node, say 3

-given distribution of connections (say Poisson distribution with given mean)

Thanks

Comment: It's now almost 7 years later, but for anyone who might be reading this with the same (first part of your) question: the `networkx` module now has a function `random_regular_graph(k,n)` which chooses a random graph on n vertices such that each vertex has exactly k connections (i.e., has degree k)! Be warned, though: sometimes there are no such graphs. For instance, there are no 3-regular graphs on any odd number of vertices (and so `random_regular_graph(3, 5)` will throw an exception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using NetworkX you might try the "configuration model". 
This was discussed in the SO question [Generating a graph with certain degree distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328837/generating-a-graph-with-certain-degree-distribution)

In graph theory terminology the number of connections is called "degree".  And graphs with uniform degree (all nodes the same) are called "regular graphs".

Answer (score 3):

First you have to define a graph data type:

```
class Graph:
  def __init__(self):
    self.related_nodes = set()
```

Then you define a factory function for this data structure that does what you want. For example:

```
def build_n_edge_graph(n):
  nodes = [Graph() for _ in n]
  for i, node in enumerate(nodes):
    for j in range(n):
      if i != j:
        n.related.add(node)
```

(untested!)

Or some other algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you should

1. decide how many nodes you will have
2. generate the number of links per node in your desired distribution - make sure the sum is even
3. start randomly connecting pairs of nodes until all link requirements are satisfied

There are a few more constraints - no pair of nodes should be connected more than once, no node should have more than (number of nodes - 1) links, maybe you want to ensure the graph is fully connected - but basically that's it.