# Given a graph's nodes degree sequence, how do find the distribution?

Tags: python, networkx, entropy, degrees

If I have the Zachary Karate Club graph and if I make the assumption that this is representative of all KCs, how do I use Maximum Entropy to determine the probability distribution this degree sequence comes from?

My goal is to sample a sequence of length L that can produce a graph like the Karate Club of and order of magnitude larger (340 nodes minimum)?

A similar question on SO is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328837/generating-a-graph-with-certain-degree-distribution) where it would be great if I can call something like:

`nx.utils.create_degree_sequence(340,karate_club_graph().degree().values)`